# Find unassigned Elastic IPs

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, fog

I'm trying to find all of the unassigned Elastic IPs using Fog, but it appears that the filtering in `Fog::Compute::AWS::Addresses` doesn't allow you to filter on empty values.

For example,

```
ips = Fog::Compute.new(credentials).addresses.all('domain' => 'vpc', 'instance-id' => '')
```

returns an empty array, but

```
ips = Fog::Compute.new(credentials).addresses.all('domain' => 'vpc').find_all {|eip| eip.server.nil? }
```

results in the list I'm looking for. However, we have a large number of Elastic IPs, and the latter method is incredibly slow.

Is there any way to filter for empty values in Fog? Or maybe a more efficient way to comb through the results to get the list I'm looking for?

Comment: Why not `'instance-id' => nil` ?

Comment: @Beartech That also resulted in an empty array.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the system you are using, but can you use `.where()`? As in `.addresses.where( 'domain' => 'vpc' ).where( 'instance-id' => '' ) .

Comment: The fact that the second one works makes me think that the column is `null` because `.nil?` returns true in that query. But a blank string like `''` is not nil.

Comment: @Beartech It's a REST API mapped to a model after the request. I suspect the issues lies in Fog's parameter constructor because I know Amazon's API is capable of filter on blank values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact answer to my question, but I found a faster way to accomplish my task. `eip.server` will trigger Fog to attempt to look up the server resource, so if you can get faster results by using `eip.server_id` instead. I.e.,

```
ips = Fog::Compute.new(credentials).addresses.all('domain' => 'vpc').find_all {|eip| eip.server_id.nil? }
```