# How to find the unallocated Elastic Ips in AWS EC2 using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I need to find all unallocated elasstic Ips using AWS CLI.

I am trying `aws ec2 describe-addresses --region eu-west-1`

can see entries as follows

```
{
            "PublicIp": "52.50.106.17",
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-205cc745"
        },
        {
            "Domain": "vpc",
            "InstanceId": "i-fff12747",
            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-279dfe7c",
            "AssociationId": "eipassoc-c92f5ead",
            "NetworkInterfaceOwnerId": "463466179279",
            "PublicIp": "52.30.89.148",
            "AllocationId": "eipalloc-3367c656",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.29.72.93"
        },
```

How can I find only Ips which are not allocated to any of the instances.

I am trying

`aws ec2 describe-addresses --region eu-west-1 --filter Name=instance-id,Value="null"`

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Filters[0]: "Value", must be one of: Name, Values
```

Can you please suggest how can I find unallocated Ips.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Do not add `value = null` just use Values="" check below command to filter them it will work.

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --region us-east-1 --filter Name="instance-id",Values=""
```

Comment: This returns no results for me (and I do have elastic IPs, they are returned if I don't specify a filter). I can use `Values="*"` to find all allocated IPs, but would love to know how to find the unallocated ones (other than getting all of them and manually filtering out the allocated ones).

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832460/how-can-i-select-all-elastic-ips-that-are-not-assigned-to-an-ec2-instance